# Apply with different argument value

Tags: r, rstudio

I wanted to do apply on a matrix

```
val=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
cpm <- apply(mat,2,function(x) (x/val[x])*1000000)
```

I need to use val matrix which contains 6 values, same as column number, I should use each number of val matrix for each columns.

How can I handle it?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what `val` contains or what output you want.

Comment: its not clear what you want, but `mapply` might help (if you actually have a data.frame rather than a matrix

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you matrix `mat` is:

```
mat <- matrix(1:30,ncol=6)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21   26
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22   27
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23   28
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24   29
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25   30
```

and

```
val=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

A solution to your problem is:

```
cpm <- lapply(1:ncol(mat), 
   function(k, mtx, vec) (mtx[,k]/vec[k])*1000000, mtx=mat, vec=val)

matrix(unlist(cpm),ncol=ncol(mat))

      [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]
[1,] 1e+06 3000000 3666667 4000000 4200000 4333333
[2,] 2e+06 3500000 4000000 4250000 4400000 4500000
[3,] 3e+06 4000000 4333333 4500000 4600000 4666667
[4,] 4e+06 4500000 4666667 4750000 4800000 4833333
[5,] 5e+06 5000000 5000000 5000000 5000000 5000000
```